# Orthonormal basis: Countable $\infty$ vs. Uncountable $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, infinity

My doubt is the following, when you create an orthonormal basis for a space, the number of coefficients in each vector, and the number of vectors is equal to the dimension of the space (at least in finite dimensional spaces).
For example the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

What happens when we consider infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces?

For instance, let $\mathcal{L}_2(-\pi ,\pi) $ be the collections of functions $\chi =\{x(t):-\pi \leq t \leq \pi\}$ for which $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x^2(t)|dt<\infty$. Define the vector addition and scalar multiplication coordinatewise such that we end up with a Hilbert space.

My text book says that there's a set of vectors $\{z_n:n=0,\pm1,...\}$ that is a complete orthonormal sequence in $\mathcal{L}_2(-\pi ,\pi)$.

My question is, I know that every single $x(t)$ has an infinite dimension, since we are considering a continuous function, but not **countable infinite**, while  the number of vectors $z_n$ is clearly countable infinite.

That makes me think, **isn't necessary that the number of components in a vector** **of the "basis" and the number of vectors that form the latter** **coincide?**

Hopefully you will shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is that a function $x=x(t)$ is identified by its values at each point $t\in[-\pi, \pi]$. In other words, you propose the following basis for the space $L^2([-\pi , \pi])$; 
$$
\{ e_{t_0}\ :\ t_0\in[-\pi, \pi]\}, $$ 
where we define 
$$
e_{t_0}(t):=\begin{cases} 1, & t=t_0,\\ 0, & t\ne t_0, \end{cases}$$ 
in analogy with the standard basis $\{e_j\ :\ j=1,\ldots,n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$.

This is a very natural intuition, but there is a subtlety; the elements of $L^2([-\pi, \pi])$ really are *equivalence classes* of functions, up to equality at almost all points (that is, two functions are considered equal if they agree up to a set of measure zero). Now, all functions $e_{t_0}$ are equal to zero at almost all points, so they count as the null function in $L^2$. This is where your intuition breaks down.

Comment: Okey, so there's "standard basis" analogue in the space that I'm working on, but lets take another sequence that serves as a "basis" let's say some set of vectors $z_n$ such that I can write $x(t)$ as a infinite linear combination of those vectors, (having that the $\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\beta_k|^2<\infty$). How many $z_n$ vectors do I need? infinite of course, but what infinite? what's the dimension of my $L^2$ space? infinite, but what infinite? Maybe I'm rounding in circles in a nonsense but that's my main doubt.

Comment: These are reasonable questions, which are difficult, don't worry if you feel you don't understand immediately. The space L2 admits countably infinite orthonormal bases. For example, the trigonometric system is such a countable base.

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, I am far away my field of knowledge but I find this topics highly interesting (even for an economist). I'll keep studying about this, and hopefully I'll understand it. In the meantime I'll accept you answer .

Comment: (I know how you feel, I am a mathematician and I took an economics course of Bottazzi, maybe you know him. I was suffering). Anyway, it seems to me that nobody mentioned the short answer; letting $e_n(t):=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{in t}, $ it holds that $$f=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}_n e_n, \quad \forall f\in L^2(-\pi, \pi), $$ where $\hat{f}_n$ is a sequence of complex numbers (the so-called Fourier coefficients). The sum converges in the sense of the $L^2$ norm. Thus, every element of the space $L^2(-\pi, \pi)$ can be identified by the countable sequence of its Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Indeed I am working on of spectral analysis of time series, and basically I wanted to dig a little bit deeper and not just to assume "ok, Fourier Transform is blabla" so I started reading a little bit about the mathematical concepts behind. I personally don't know him but I've heard about him. Quindi imagino che sei italiano, oppure hai studiato in Italia!

Comment: (Yes, I am Italian, my first name is difficult to find elsewhere :-) )

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed specify a member of ${\mathcal L}_2(-\pi,\pi)$ with countably many real numbers.  That doesn't say you have to: you can also choose to specify
the values $f(t)$ for all $t \in (-\pi,\pi)$ (modulo the non-uniqueness due to the fact that these are really 
equivalence classes of functions rather than functions: you can change $f$ on a set of measure $0$ and it's the same
member of $\mathcal L_2$).  But those uncountably many choices are not independent.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, I feel that your answer is very related with Giuseppe's one, but unfortunately I am not getting everything, I am kinda new in this topic. I ask you to please read the comment in the other answer, maybe I did't express clearly what I am asking.

Comment: Actually, this is the best answer, not mine. The real problem is not the almost everywhere equivalence, as I claim. Indeed, $L^\infty$ is also defined up to such equivalence, yet it is not *separable* (which is the theoretical property that enables $L^2(-\pi, \pi)$ to support countable orthonormal bases).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some examples might help?

One basis is the set $P_n(x/\pi)$ where $(1-x^2)P_n''(x)-2xP_n'=(-n)(n+1)$ and $P(1)=1$. These are the [Legendre Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). You can get them by performing the Graham-Schmidt Orthonormalization Process on polynomials starting with $P_0(x)=1$ and $P_1(x)=x$.

Turns out $\int_{-1}^1P_m(x)P_n(x)dx=\delta_{mn}\frac{2}{2m+1}$ where $\delta_{mn}$ is the Kronecker Delta function.

So if $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_kP_k(x)$

$c_k=\int_{-1}^1f(x)P_k(x)(\frac{2k+1}{2})dx$

So your basis is countable, and, for a given function, you only need one at most countable set of coefficients.

Another possible basis, the [Hermite Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials). Slightly tweaked for the interval in question. They are solutions to a specific differential equation. They can be generated by performing the Graham-Schmidt procedure for polynomials integrated over all space against the weight function $e^{-x^2}$. A similar process as above also gives you your needed coefficients.

Fourier Series would be especially appropriate considering the interval.

The [Stone-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) is really important in this context as well.

Comment: Indeed I am reading about the Fourier series, and the theory behind the well known formula, what I mean is that a time series $x(t)$ is a continuous periodic function in the interval $(\pi, ,\pi)$ there are infinitely points in this segment, but uncountable infinitely. But the "basis" are an sequence of infinite (countable) vectors with components $e^{I \lambda_n t}$ for $n=0, \pm1,..$. The number of vectors in the basis doesn't match with the number of elements in the time series. This is my point

Comment: Ah okay! Consider that each basis vector contributes its own uncountable number of points. A function expressed in that basis is an at most countable sum of the basis functions, each of those functions being its own collection of uncountably many points.

As to how the countable sums of the uncountable sets of points can approximate some other uncountable set of points I think the SW theorem will help. Truth be told I've forgotten how the theorem works and need to review it.

Comment: It's clear that I need a lot of theoretical tools that unfortunately I don't have, I am playing to know maths although I'm an economist. Thanks for the tip, I'll read about it!

Comment: You might also want to look into countable, dense subsets. It overlaps with the themes here. For example, the rationals are dense over the reals. It's always possible to find a rational number arbitrarily close to a given real number even though there are only countably many rationals.